# Adding index to the Empty Dataframe pandas Python 3.5.0

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.5

I have create an empty dataframe as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["steps","amount","token_id"])
```

Now I want to add index to it. The index is not readily defined, but are going to set by the program in run time. I tried the following:

```
df.index = ["new1"]
```

But got error. I want to know how an empty dataframe can be set with the new index.
I want the outcome be like the following:

```
         amount steps token_id
new1    NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Please let me know how is this possible.

Comment: `df.loc['new1'] = np.nan`

Comment: @MykolaZotko Thank you for the comment. I tried this `df.loc['new1'] = None`. And it worked.